# Need Help Setting MSI Pro MP271AP 27" Monitor to 100Hz in Ubuntu

Tags: display, display-resolution, msi

I recently purchased an MSI Pro MP271AP 27" monitor with a 100Hz refresh rate. While the monitor functions perfectly at 100Hz in Windows, I'm encountering difficulties setting it to the same refresh rate in Ubuntu. Whenever I attempt to change the refresh rate to 100Hz in Ubuntu, the screen briefly goes black before reverting back to 75Hz after a few seconds. I've tried adjusting the settings through the display preferences without success.

Could anyone please provide guidance on how to properly set the refresh rate to 100Hz in Ubuntu for this particular monitor model, considering it functions correctly in Windows? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
jorge$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x25) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 330mm
    Identifier: 0x42f
    Timestamp:  711092
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    RANDR Emulation: 1 
    non-desktop: 0 
            supported: 0, 1
    1920x1080 (0x25) 220.750MHz -HSync +VSync *current +preferred
    h: width  1920 start 2064 end 2264 total 2608 skew    0 clock  84.64KHz
    v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1130           clock  74.91Hz
```

[image: hz_screenshot]